# How to remove wordpress default jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have troubles with Wordpress. I need to remove this includions

```
*-> /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4<br>
-> /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1*
```

As you can see on the picture below, I'm using own compiled and minified version of scripts, where I also have jquery...

I would like to remove that older default wordpress version from including.?

[image]

Here is some code that I have tried before posting this:

```
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}

add_action( 'wp_jquery_customer', 'my_jquery_enqueue' );
add_action( 'wp_nopriv_jquery_customer', 'my_jquery_enqueue' );
```

Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `wp_enqueue_scripts`

so your function should look like this:

```
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_enqueue' );
```

More Details your can read about `wp_enqueue_scripts` at:

[Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: @AndrejV. your are Welcome :)